# Confusion about -c option in bash

Tags: bash, positional-parameter

From the bash man-page:

> ```
>   -c        If  the  -c  option  is  present, then commands are read from the first non-option
>             argument command_string.  If there are arguments  after  the  command_string,  the
>             first  argument  is assigned to $0 and any remaining arguments are assigned to the
>             positional parameters.
> ```

So I created a "script" file named `foo.sh`, containing the single line

```
echo par 0 is $0, par 1 is $1
```

, set it to executable, and invoked it as

```
bash -c ./foo.sh x y
```

I expected to see *par 0 is x, par 1 is y*, but it was printed *par 0 is ./foo.sh, par 1 is*.

In what respect did I misunderstand the man-page?

**UPDATE** Perhaps to clarify it (since my question seems to have given rise to some confusion): My goal is to execute `foo.sh`, but making it  believe that its real name is not *foo.sh*, but *x*.

Comment: `bash -c "./foo.sh x y"` ... always quote your full command.

Comment: I see that this works. If you also can explain WHY quoting is needed here, please post it as an answer. The man page says that after `-c` comes the command, and after this come the individual arguments. I would have expected that your solution would try to run a file named _./foo.sh x y_, but it seems that you are right here.

Comment: Even shorter - Just answer the question "What is my command?". If your command includes arguments, then they must be part of the command and quoting ensures that the single command contains all parts. Unquoted, the "command" is just the first non-option thing found after `-c` and everything after it is ignored and left for the invoking shell to interpret. So `bash -c "command a b"` the full command processed is `"command a b"` where both arguments are part of the command. With `bash -c command a b` the full command is `command` and `a` and `b` are not part of the command.

Comment: I see! I thought of "command" as being the file to be executed, but the meaning here is more akin to "command line":

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would see the behaviour you wanted with this :

```
bash -c "$(cat foo.sh)" x y
```

Comment: This is great!! This makes me understand it best.

Answer (score 3):

The inline script (the `./foo.sh` argument just after the `-c` option) is not passing any argument to `./foo.sh`:

```bash
bash -c ./foo.sh x y
```

This is the inline script:

```bash
./foo.sh
```

This first level script indeed receives `x` as argument `$0` and `y` as argument `$1`.
But it does not pass any argument when invoking `foo.sh`.
It explains why `foo.sh` only see itself as the `$0` argument, and nothing as argument `$1`.

Now try with this

```bash
bash -c './foo.sh "$@"' x y
```

And its output is:

```bash
par 0 is ./foo.sh, par 1 is y
```

This is because `"$@"` does not expand argument `$0` which is the script itself.

Comment: I understand that your proposed solution works, but I was interested in why my version does not work. Seeing it fromt the viewpoint of an execve call, i.e. doing something in the spirit of `execve("./foo.sh", ["x", "y"], ENV)` (didn't use exact C syntax for brevity), i.e. making foo.sh believe that it is invoced under the name _x_. But perhaps relating this bash invocation to an _execve_ call is a bit like comparing apples and pears?

Comment: @user1934428 It is because there is an extra level (note the **inline script** in the answer). Putting `./foo.sh` there is one thing, and putting the content of `./foo.sh` there, is another. You are missing this extra layer.

Comment: @WeijunZhou : Now I finally understand why I receive the respective output for my concrete example!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not on `-c` option.
The problem is on the script `foo.sh`, in a script `sh` if you take the parameter with `$0` you will have ever the script/command name.
So the script should do:

```
echo par 0 is $1, par 1 is $2
```

and all should work fine.

Comment: The inline script is not passing any argument to `foo.sh`, so shifting the argument index as you did in your explanation, will just show empty.

Comment: Of course this would produce x and y, but this is not what I want to achieve. I want to "lie about the script name", as the man-page promises _The assignment to $0 sets the name of the shell, which  is used in warning and error messages._

Comment: It would not work fine. I want to see the output _par 0 is x, par 1 is y_, i.e. I want to bind $0 (usually the script name) to x.